# Adding haystack's full text search to edx-platform

Tags: python, django, edx

I'm trying to extend the edx-platform by adding full-text search, but I'm having trouble understanding how to retrieve data from mongodb. Does anyone have any experience with edx? How can one access data in a `Courses.objects.all()` manner?

Thanks!

A.

Comment: EdX doesn't look like it uses Haystack. Haystack doesn't query directly from the Database and works from django models. What have you tried?

Comment: I know it does not use haystack. I want to add full-text search for courses, but need to retrieve them in order to create an index. Just managed to find a way to retrieve all courses by using the modulestore under the xmodule package. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some sub-project created by edX called edX search, which will employ searching in a manner closer to the way you want. They use ElasticSearch directly without the Haystack lib .. have a look and let me if you find it useful: https://github.com/edx/edx-search

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/
as well as https://github.com/selvinsource/mongodb-datamining-shell

Hope it helps.

Comment: That mongodb-datamining-shell seems interesting, though kind out of the scope of this question. Thanks anyway.